# Add .jar files into a git repository

Tags: java, git, github

I have a project on eclipse where recently i created a new folder called lib and added some .jar files inside.
I cannot seem to commit the changes to git. It just doesnt appear in the tracked list of files..
I have removed .jar from .gitignore in my branch and commited the changes, and still the same.

Comment: the question is: why do you want to check in jars in the first place? Why don't you use a build tool like maven or gradle to resolve and retrieve dependencies?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Even with maven projects you may encounter jars not present as a maven artifact.  Especially for legacy projects or when using third-party repositories since gone.  We enclose those jars and provide instructions for installing them in the local repository for new developer. Maven is simply not the knee-jerk answer to this.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen for this reason the nexus repository server is available...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle a repository server is not a knee jerk solution to that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put your files in the project package, but you didn't put them under version control. All you need is to add them to VCS by "git add" command. Here is good [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).

You should use this command in git bash or in terminal (if you have added git to path)

Also I recommend you to use build manager as Maven, Gradle or Ant to add you dependencies. Good luck!

Comment: in case git refuses to add the jars you may add the  `-f` switch to your git  command line.

Answer (score 15):

The way I got it working for me was -

```
git add --force /path/to/the/NAME_Of_THE_JAR.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

in the  .gitignore file present in your project, you need to make sure that you allow *.jar files to be pushed. In my case, *.jar files was listed in ignore list. So I removed it from that list and git was able to detect it and I was able to push it.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify if your .jar is needed to be added using the command `git diff`, git will indicate if you need to add the files to your repository.
Them use `git add .` and your files will be available for commit.

Answer (score 1):

If the `lib` folder is ignored by `.gitignore` you can force adding them to the VCS using the following command:

```
git add /path/to/lib -f
```