# Build tools for Java

Tags: java, git, gradle, version-control, ant

I am currently taking some online courses to refresh my knowledge of Java and Python. I am also practicing using Git and GitHub on two different machines to get a feel for version control (which is what spawned this question).

Essentially, I had some JAR files on one machine that my school project is dependent on. When I was finished with the project, I pushed it to my GitHub repository, and then tried to clone that repository on a new computer.

When I looked at the cloned repositories, I noticed that the JAR files weren't there. So after a lot of digging, I found that all JAR files are ignored in my .gitignore (I downloaded a generic .gitignore template for netbeans).

I decided to research why you might want to ignore .JAR files. I didn't find an answer, but I did find [this question and it's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068608/add-jar-files-into-a-git-repository) on how to add .JAR files. I already figured that part out, but the answer-er also said:

*"Also I recommend you to use build manager as Maven, Gradle or Ant to add you dependencies."*

So my questions:

**1.) What does using a third party tool to build an application have to do with adding .JAR files to a GitHub repository?**

**2.) What is the reason for defaulting to ignoring JAR files?**

**3.) Should a new computer programmer care about using one of these tools? (I barely understand the difference between building and compiling any way).**

Comment: I notice that there are two votes to close already. Please read both of the questions. While one could be construed as opinion based, the other is definitely a technical question. I want to know why the lady or gentleman would make the quoted statement in reference to pushing JAR files.

Comment: Altough a bit late, i have tried to address your question in a more detailed fashion.

Comment: @Glains Thank you for your very well written answer. It is indeed even more revealing than the one I accepted. I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is when a new and more detailed answer is given after an old answer is accepted. You both answered my question well, but you specifically addressed my "Opinion based question" which is kind as it is frowned upon to ask such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version control tools like git, svn, and cvs are meant to version code, not binaries and in particular not compiled code.

Adding jars to a project's source also makes that project much larger.

If you did want to "save" your jars somewhere you would use a repository and a dependency management tool e.g. Maven Central, Ivy, or Gradle.

### EDIT

You develop a project i.e. you write code and commit it to git. You use git to handle different versions of your code and collaboration with other developers. Your code may have dependencies e.g. log4j or others. You fetch those dynamically from a jar repository using Maven / Ivy / Gradle. That way, I can clone your project (source) quickly and then fetch the dependencies from a central source. It avoids replication of libraries inside N different projects.

Comment: Do I interpret your answer correctly: Using one of those tools is a handy way clone a  finished project and be able to compile the working code on a new computer without pushing a lot of extra stuff (in the form of imported libraries) to GitHub?

Comment: See my edit in the response

Answer (score 1):

A version control system, by definition, should assist developers to manage changes made to the source code over time. You can imagine it as a database that keeps track of all changes. This allows multiple developers to concurrently work on the same project.

Now, since we like to reuse code and not write everything from scratch, projects usually depend on other ones, thus becoming a dependency of your project. However, as you change your source code, so do the developers of your libraries. Therefore, you should depend on a specific version of a library to prevent pulling unintended changes. This is where build tools like Gradle and Maven come into play. You simply declare the dependencies of your project while referencing specific versions of that dependencies.

The following example is from Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

These tools make it is very easy to keep track of your dependencies and used versions.

But why dont you commit your libraries to your version control system as well?

- Libraries take up space and slow down operations. It could take serveral minutes to clone a repository instead of seconds.
- You would have to upload a new version of the library each time you increment the version you are depending on.
- Some builds are system dependent. While not that important for Java programs, you usually compile C++ programs for a particular system. With build-tools, you can just fetch the source code locally and build the correct version on your machine.

> What does using a third party tool to build an application have to do with adding .JAR files to a GitHub repository?

You elimitante the need to upload them.

> What is the reason for defaulting to ignoring JAR files?

Above reasons should give you a pretty good hint. In fact, a lot of files are commonly ignored by default, have a look at a collection of templates [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

> Should a new computer programmer care about using one of these tools?

If you start to work in a team, you can merge your code manually, but you will quickly notice that it is very time-costly and error prone. It is never a wrong idea to start early with VCS, since from my knowledge this topic often not taught at university, but mandatory later at work.